# Is there any limitation in python when handling long file paths?

Tags: python

I am writing a file copying utility in Python. But I am getting some error messages when processing files with very long file paths.

I suspect Python has some limitations when handling very long file paths.

Comment: -1: No OS listed.  No code.  No error messages.  Blame python without even listing the OS that's having the problem.  Can you use these long file names from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many file systems don't support long filenames, so it's probably a limitation of the OS or your file system.

There are also OS-specific issues like API limitations (e.g. [in the Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath)).

Comment: Thanks.Yes you are correct my file path has 261 characters. Definitely this is not handle by the win32 ENV.